# Existence of a bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

If $S$ is a closed subspace of a real normed space $(X,\lVert \cdot \rVert)$ and there is a vector $x \in X \setminus S$, show that exist a bounded linear funcional $l \in X^{*}\setminus \{0_{X^{*}}\}$ such that $l(s)=0$ for all $s \in S$. Here $0_{X^{*}}$ is the zero operator.

Any idea how can I prove this result?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Could you please give me a more detailed answer?

Comment: First define the functional on the linear span of $S$ and $x$.  Then extend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** Apply the [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) to the closed set $S$ and the compact set $\{x\}$.

Comment: By that theorem I know that exist a bounded lineral functional $l$ and $s,t$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that  $l(x)<s<t<l(s)$ for all $s\in S$. What can I conclude from this?

Comment: @DiegoVargas You're overloading the variable $s$. Regardless, assume (towards a contradiction) that $l(y)\neq0$ for some $y\in S$.

Comment: Sorry for that I didn´t realize it! Did you mean the same $l$ of the H-B theorem? Or do I need to pick up another functional?

Comment: @DiegoVargas The same functional.

Comment: Sorry I can't see any contradiction. Could you give me another hint please

Comment: @DiegoVargas $l(S)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  How many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are there?

Comment: Only $\mathbb{R}$ or $\{0\}$ if we consider it as a real vector space. As I am supposing that $l(y)\neq 0$ for some $y \in S$, the only posibility is $l(S)=\mathbb{R}$ So $l(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ implies that $x\in S$ wich is a contradiction. Is it right? I don't see how to use H-B.

Comment: @DiegoVargas It's almost correct.  Since $l(S)=\mathbb R$ we know $l(x)$ is less than every real number, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for yor time and help! @Aweygan

Comment: @DiegoVargas You're welcome